# Specify week range from Sunday to Saturday in SQL Assistance Teradata using WEEKNUMBER_OF_YEAR

Tags: sql, range, teradata

I have the code which gives me Week Number:

`,'Week' ||' '||trim(WEEKNUMBER_OF_YEAR (DATA_DATE, 'ISO'))     AS "WEEK of DATA_DATE"`

This gives me week No as: "Week 8" (or Week 9 or Week 11) where "Week 8" Defines Days from Monday to Sunday, I am looking for days to be defined from **Sunday to Saturday** .
`DATA_DATE` Format is `DATA_DATE DATE FORMAT 'YY/MM/DD',`

Can anyone please advise on this.

Thanks,
Deepak

Comment: Did you try `WEEKNUMBER_OF_YEAR (DATA_DATE, 'TERADATA')`?

Comment: Thanks Dnoeth, it is giving me correct day range but if I yearly data, it is starting with "Week 0" instead of "Week 1"

Comment: Well, you have to specify the rules how a week number is calculated, what is the starting week of a year, are there partial weeks over new year, etc.

Comment: This works well, it starts from Week 1 (Sunday to Saturday)
,'Week' ||' '||trim(WEEKNUMBER_OF_YEAR (DATA_DATE) + 1)   AS "WEEK of DATA_DATE"

Comment: Of course you should test this across several years.